# Retrieve data from python script and save to sqllite database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I have a python query which retrieves data through an API. The data returned is a dictionary. I want to save the data in sqlite3 database. There are two main columns('scan','tests'). I'm only interested in the data inside these two columns e.g. 'grade': 'D+', 'likelihood_indicator': 'MEDIUM'.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from httpobs.scanner.local import scan
import sqlite3

website_to_scan = 'digitalnz.org'
scan_site = scan(website_to_scan)
df = pd.DataFrame(scan_site)

print(scan_site)
print(df)`
```

Results of print(scan_site):

[image]

Results of print(df) attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you have set up your table in sqlite but essentially you would write an `INSERT INTO` SQL clause and use the `connection.execute()` function in Python and pass your SQL string as an argument.

Its difficult to give a more precise answer for your question (i.e. code) because you haven't declared the connection variable. Lets imagine you already have your sqlite DB set up with the connection:

```
connection_variable.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name 
(column_name1, column_name2) VALUES (value1, value2);""")
```

Comment: The issue is I don't know how to convert the indexes in my result to columns. once they are converted I can save the data by creating the table.

Comment: So your ```column_name1``` would be the name of the column in your sqlite table and your ```value1``` would be ```df[indices of the data you want to put into column_name1]```

Comment: from the screenshot of the results. I want to get rid of column headings 'scan' & 'tests', create column 'grade' and store 'D+' as the value. Sorry, I'm not good with this, just trying to build something meaningful for my work.

Comment: Okay so this is more of a Pandas df question. It sounds like you want to create a new column ```df['Grade'] = 'D+' ``` and then remove the other columns that are not needed and make sure that the df exactly matches the table you want to insert into then once the df is ready you can use the ```df.to_sql('your_tableName', connection_variable, if_exists='append', index=False)```  you may want to check the Pandas docs to check the appropriate arguments for your specific use case. The above arguments assume that your data do not include an index and you want to add duplicates as new records.